# Google calendar API all-day events timezone

Tags: python, date, datetime, google-api, google-calendar-api

Using python 3.6, requests==2.22.0, Postgres DB

In my application, I have user's calendars representations that people can schedule on by selecting from free time that is available to them.
A user's calendar has the timezone stored for that user.
I am generating events from events that I get from my user's calendars - those events are used as blocks that are already taken and cannot be booked. (conflicts)
I then store the events in my database in a simple object representation, with a start and end DateTimes. (Postgres stores DateTimes in UTC format)
I am querying for events using single events queries (as shown below) and for multiple events over a date-range - all of the queries are working well.
I am using the query param: `timeZone=UTC` for all calls, and all events.

**What I am trying to understand:**
How do I build a start/end DateTime for an all-day event that I fetch from the API?
I want to generate a single, or a multiple day object event that would represent the event exactly as it is in the user's calendar.
I generated an all-day event in my Google calendar (my calendar is in Pacific tz), in order to test what I need.
I have zero issues with generating any other (non all-day) events, and retrieving in UTC works well for me.

I am currently querying for single events like this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calendar_id>/events/<event_id>?timeZone=UTC'
response = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers)
```

response.json() outputs:

```
{'kind': 'calendar#event',
 'etag': <some_tag>,
 'id': <some_id>,
 'status': 'confirmed',
 'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=<some_eid>&ctz=UTC',
 'created': '2019-11-20T21:30:19.000Z',
 'updated': '2019-11-20T21:53:39.298Z',
 'summary': 'TESTING ALL DAY',
 'creator': {'email': <some_email>, 'self': True},
 'organizer': {'email': <some_email>, 'self': True},
 'start': {'date': '2019-11-21'},  <-- all-day events have date, not dateTime
 'end': {'date': '2019-11-22'},    <-- all-day events have date, not dateTime
 'iCalUID': <some_id>,
 'sequence': 0,
 'reminders': {'useDefault': False,
  'overrides': [{'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}]}}
```

Because I requested the event(s) in UTC, should I be assuming that the dates have been converted to UTC or not?
A possible flow:

1. Generating DateTimes from the Dates, assuming it was converted to UTC
2. Localizing it to the user's local tz
3. Take the Dates, and use it to generate the actual DateTimes
4. Store in the DB, as back to UTC

What are the implications for user's calendars that are on the cusp? (like New Zealand, or Alaska)

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the dates are coming in UTC. What's the problem with those countries? You'll still have to localize the user's local timezones.

Comment: @AndresDuarte Can I assume it was generated in UTC? If the service is generating the dates from the calendar TZ, then for some countries (on the cusp) when localizing the date might be different. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Yes. You can check it with the `created` field because you know the time when you created the event, and see if it was your local time or UTC. About your other doubt I'm not being able to help you.

Comment: I disagree with the above comments. For all day events, it doesn't make sense to assume that the absolute points of time representing the start and end of the event are in UTC. If the event was an all-day event on 2021-10-01 in say New York, its duration is 2021-10-01T04:00:00.000Z to 2021-10-02T03:59:59.999Z, etc. The problem is that Google does not supply any timezone for all-day events so I guess you'd have to assume the timezone of the organizer or any resources booked? It's a shame Google doesn't automatically resolve startTime and endTime also for all-day events.